# Sharepoint Online - Task with feedback

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I require to do the following:

- User A will create a task or record and assign it to User B
- An Email will be sent to User B (Using Flow) that a new Task has been assigned to him
- User B has to set a company responsible for this task (normal text) and the expected end date
- Once the task is completed, User B need to set it to completed, and an automatic email will be sent to User A that this task is done

I have faced the following complications:

- When assigning a task to a user, I cannot set that only the creator and the one assigned to this task are able to edit it. Therefore my solution was to create two custom lists, the first one is where the new task will be added. The second one will be a copy of the new task plus the additional required information. This will be created using flow, however, i am unable to set the Created By record to be equal to User B, and therefore this will not help.
- Is it possible to allow the user to edit a record for x number of times?

Note: I am trying to solve this without creating custom lists using asp.net since I do not have VS at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Item level permissions**:  This is possible, you can change the item level permissions in the List Setting ==> Advanced Settings.
   [image]
2. **A number of edits allowed**, *this is not possible out of the box*, you will need to create something custom.  Having said this, since you are using Flow, you could consider moving items to another list e.g. If Status = Approved move the item to another list which users will not have access.  See this for more details about moving items using MS Flow: http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/04/29/auto-move-sharepoint-list-items-using-flow/